# Bar Chart - Insert text on the bars

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to use this latex module (copied from [here](https://www.overleaf.com/articles/satish-kumars-cv/dngwrghdxxqh)) to draw a bar chart.

```
\newcounter{barcount}


% draw a bar chart
% param 1: width
% param 2: height
% param 3: border color
% param 4: label text color
% param 5: label bg color
% param 6: cat 1 color
\newenvironment{barchart}[8]{

    \newcommand{\barwidth}{0.35}
    \newcommand{\barsep}{0.2}

    % param 1: overall percent
    % param 2: label
    % param 3: cat 1 percent
    % param 4: cat 2 percent
    % param 5: cat 3 percent
    \newcommand{\baritem}[5]{

        \pgfmathparse{##3+##4+##5}
         \let\perc\pgfmathresult

        \pgfmathparse{#2}
         \let\barsize\pgfmathresult

        \pgfmathparse{\barsize*##3/100}
         \let\barone\pgfmathresult

        \pgfmathparse{\barsize*##4/100}
         \let\bartwo\pgfmathresult

        \pgfmathparse{\barsize*##5/100}
         \let\barthree\pgfmathresult

        \pgfmathparse{(\barwidth*\thebarcount)+(\barsep*\thebarcount)}
         \let\barx\pgfmathresult

        \filldraw[fill=#6, draw=none] (0,-\barx) rectangle (\barone,-\barx-\barwidth);
        \filldraw[fill=#7, draw=none] (\barone, -\barx) rectangle (\barone+\bartwo,-\barx-\barwidth);
        \filldraw[fill=#8, draw=none] (\barone+\bartwo,-\barx ) rectangle (\barone+\bartwo+\barthree,-\barx-\barwidth);

        \node [label=180:\colorbox{#5}{\textcolor{#4}{##2}}] at (0,-\barx-0.175) {};
        \addtocounter{barcount}{1}
    }
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \setcounter{barcount}{0}

}
{\end{tikzpicture}}
```

and it's usage is like this:

```
\begin{barchart}{10}{16}{sectcol}{textcol}{sectcol}{maincol}{secondcol}{thirdcol}
    \baritem{100}{Python}{20}{20}{0}
\end{barchart}
```

now what I need is to write text on the bars. like below:
[image: sample of a bar chart with text on the bars]

Is it possible to change the module to do so?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome! Yes, it is. However, users will be much more likely to help you if you provide a complete example that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`. In your case the color definitions are missing, for instance.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than using environments and macros with up to eight mandatory arguments, I suggest using pgf keys. The code then reduces to

```
\begin{barchart}
  \baritem{Python}{40/scipy,40/scikit-learn}
  \baritem{R}{40/tidywise}
  \baritem{Pft}{30/hibernate,30/sleep,40/eat}
\end{barchart}
```

but you can still fully control the appearance by changing the pgf keys (either their initial value or the optional argument). Here is the full MWE (which is how on this site codes usually get shared):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\newcounter{barcount}
\tikzset{barchart/.cd,y distance/.initial=3em,
bar height/.initial=2em,width/.initial=6cm,
bar text/.style={font=\sffamily,text depth=0.25em},
description/.style={font=\sffamily,text depth=0.25em},
colors/.initial={"orange!80","blue!40","red","green!70!black"}}
\newenvironment{barchart}[1][]{%
    \tikzset{barchart/.cd,#1}%
    \newcommand{\baritem}[2]{\stepcounter{barcount}%
     \path (0,-\number\value{barcount}*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/barchart/y distance})
      coordinate (tmp) node[left=1ex,yshift=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/barchart/bar
      height}/2,/tikz/barchart/description]{##1};
     \foreach \Percentage/\Text [count=\X starting from 0]  in {##2}
     {\pgfmathsetmacro{\mycolor}{{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/barchart/colors}}[\X]}
     \path[fill=\mycolor] (tmp)      rectangle ++ 
       ({(\Percentage/100)*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/barchart/width}},
     \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/barchart/bar height}) 
     node[midway,/tikz/barchart/bar text]{\Text};
     \path (tmp) + ({(\Percentage/100)*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/barchart/width}},0)
      coordinate(tmp); }
    }
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \setcounter{barcount}{0}}
{\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}

\begin{barchart}
  \baritem{Python}{40/scipy,40/scikit-learn}
  \baritem{R}{40/tidywise}
  \baritem{Pft}{30/hibernate,30/sleep,40/eat}
\end{barchart}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I needed.

Comment: @Fateme If this answer solves your problem, could you please consider accepting it by clicking on the check mark left of it?